# Longest Mishna By Word Count

Tags: number, mishna

What is the longest **individual** Mishna?

Not asking regarding the number of Mishnayos in a Masechta,
rather by the word count of an individual Mishna
*(An example of a long Mishna is [Eduyot 6:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Eduyot.6.3), with 317 words)*

I understand it may depend on the version; asking in general

Comment: What motivated this question?

Comment: @magicker72 Was listening to a shiur on the linked Mishna where the speaker said wasn't sure if this was longest Mishna, and couldn't find if so by Googling

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: [See here](http://daf-yomi.com/forums/Message.aspx?id=62476)

המשנה הגדולה בבבלי – זבחים קי"ב א', שהיא תל"ט תיבות

Comment: @Gershon Gold I just noticed your comment. Wow, amazing that the Gemara combines all 10 Mishnayos of the last Perek of Zevachim in one gigantic Mishna that spans more than an Amud!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I analysed the mishnayot according to how they appear on [Mechon Mamre](https://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h0.htm) and how they appear on [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Mishnah).

For Mechon Mamre's mishnayot, the raw data is [here](https://zerobin.net/?034a271ddb411da3#Uy2uTlgz34T0G+qb+ipPnNllxv60Yx0U/dqvxLBBQrQ=), where I removed punctuation and eliminated mishna numbering (and secondary numbering). The word count output is [here](https://zerobin.net/?e31f9a781a47b67e#pML0Q5vB3X3yfYaJ1ApqBZWphpXvHIaxPznPXUEMw+Y=). You can sort that list, find the corresponding line in the word count output, and compare that to the raw data. (Sorry this is cumbersome, there are better ways that take longer to implement.) The top 10 longest mishnayot by word count, according to Mechon Mamre, are:

1. Eduyot 6:3 (319 words)
2. Sota 8:1 (300 words)
3. Yadayim 4:3 (290 words)
4. Yevamot 14:4 (287 words)
5. Middot 4:8 (244 words)
6. Nazir 8:1 (236 words)
7. Zevaḥim 6:9 (215 words)
8. Sanhedrin 4:5 (212 words)
9. Tamid 4:4 (206 words)
10. Bechorot 8:1 (185 words)

For Sefaria's mishnayot, the raw data is [here](https://zerobin.net/?9c4e6ff30c7c60b6#ueHM2c0VUPCdx8lZ4Bx593PrLkXiaxAse9fGRuQtCYg=) (pulled from [here](https://github.com/Sefaria/Sefaria-Export/tree/master/txt/Mishnah)), and the word count output is [here](https://zerobin.net/?b897e90cd736196e#W4Go2VAwG8LVjc7aqNrw+SydsXtsuVAONYHCHzUds84=). The top 10 longest mishnayot by word count, according to Sefaria, are:

1. Eduyot 6:3 (317 words)
2. Sota 9:15 (297 words)
3. Yadayim 4:3 (288 words)
4. Kiddushin 14:4 (255 words)
5. Tamid 4:3 (253 words)
6. Sanhedrin 10:2 (239 words)
7. Nazir 8:1 (236 words)
8. Sanhedrin 4:5 (210 words)
9. Zevaḥim 6:7 (209 words)
10. Nedarim 3:11 (196 words)

All of this relates to collections of mishnayot. However, in the printed Talmud Bavli all of the mishnayot in the fourteenth perek of Masechet Zevachim are printed as one long continuous mishnah on dapim 112a-113a. So if you are learning gemara, that is the longest mishnah you will encounter. Similarly, the gemara at the end of Pesachim (98b) combines three mishnayot into one long mishnah of 273 words.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for doing all that work to give such a detailed answer!

Comment: The two-word difference in Eduyot 6:3, by the way, is two appearances of את.

Comment: What accounts for the large discrepancies between Sefaria and Mechon Mamre? Are they just numbering the mishnayot differently, or are there significant textual variations?

Comment: @Alex Besides different numbering (induced by different break points), look at Sota 9:15 or Kiddushin 14:4 (for example) in both.

Comment: Thanks @magicker72 !
I would like to see this analysis and more, on the Mishna Sdura text I publish. I have tables summarizing and comparing the averages length of Perek of each Seder. This is useful for planning learning. Just counting the number of Mishnayot is misleading at best. For example See [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FF2_e8Q_qhfiGAwe-K9JgejB-8nShqWD/view?usp=sharing) - Nezikin has 50% more words per Perek and per Mishna than does Zeraim. It is also more complex to understand.

Comment: I added a note at the end re Zevachim ch. 14. I don't know why davka that perek was printed that way. However, it reminds me that I recall reading somewhere that the divisions of mishnayot we have today post-date the redaction of the mishnah itself and originally the mishnayot were only broken into chapters. Not sure if that's accurate, but if it is then maybe we should just be looking at the longest perek for all 6 orders.

Comment: @Avraham I appreciate your additions. However, the point of my work here was to give a definitive answer. If you're going to add to it, please do a definitive search of all mishnayot in the gemara, and not to add piecemeal.