# How many words are in mishna?

Tags: mishna

I have already seen multiple question about mishna how big it is from which year it is and all kind of that, but I'm still wondering what's the total amount of words in mishna?

Comment: Why relevant? Why don't you download it from Mechon Mamre/Sefaria and count it?

Comment: See word count output [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/127045/11501), add the numbers and come back to answer your question :->

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Avrohom and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!